# Generate random numbers between two values with floating steps

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to generate 40 random numbers between two given values with a specific **floating** step; some thing like: random(start,stop,step); where: start=5,stop=7,step=0.1
Is there any function in numpy or other python's libraries to do that directly?

Comment: What would the step parameter do?

Comment: generated numbers would be like: 5.1, 6.3, 5.6
I don't want some thing like 5.0325

Comment: Do you mean that you want your random numbers to be rounded to one digit after the dot?

Comment: Then generate the possible set of numbers and use `numpy.random.choice` to select, or round the output of any random generator of your choice

Comment: Yes. only one digit after dot.

Comment: `np.random.choice(np.arange(5, 7, 0.1), size=40)` or `np.random.uniform(5, 7, size=40).round(1)`

Comment: ... or, `rng = numpy.random.default_rng(12345);the_random_numbers = rng.integers(low=50, high=70, size=40, endpoint=True)/10`